# Can't communicate with smart IoT devices using HTTPS

Tags: http, ssl, https, iot

Every time I purchase an IoT device (smart lock, bell, plug, etc.), there usually is also a way to use it by going to `http://192.168.1.x` but there NEVER seems to be a way to communicate it using `HTTPS` securely. Is this a big problem for HTTPS? Is there a solution for this? I don't want someone on my network to look at what I am sending to my device over http but I can't use https either. What can I do?

I know that TLS certificates require a hostname to verify the authenticity but these IoT devices only tell me to open the control panel using http and local IP. Does that mean all my communication with my smart device is in plain text and open for everyone to read?

Comment: This is more on-topic at [security.se].

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean all my communication with my smart device is in plain text ...

If it is plain HTTP then yes.

> ... and open for everyone to read?

If everybody can read the communication inside your **local** network then yes. Fortunately in most local networks this is not the case. For example if you have your own WLAN which is properly secured with WPA2 and a strong password then only the ones which know this password can access the local network - but these would be able to sniff the traffic to the IoT device then.

> ... but there NEVER seems to be a way to communicate it using HTTPS securely.

This depends on the actual device, i.e. some might offer HTTPS but many still don't. If this is a problem for you since your network is open to potential attackers then you better put these devices in a separate network where only you have access to.